# Routing to indexController when trying to open another controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes

I am new to laravel4 .. I've made a simple website but when accessing `SectionController` or `CompaniesController` it redirects me to the `SryoController` while in other it works !!

that's my Route file

```
<?php

Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'SryoController@getIndex'));
Route::controller('admin/sections' ,'SectionsController');
Route::controller('admin/companies' , 'CompaniesController');
Route::controller('portfolio' , 'PortfolioController');
Route::controller('about' , 'AboutController');
Route::controller('contact' , 'ContactController');

?>
```

that's my `getIndex()` function in `SectionController`

```
public function getIndex () {

    return View::make('sections.index')
    ->with('sections' , Section::all());
 }
```

Comment: Change `Route::controller('admin/sections' ,'SectionsController');` by `Route::get('admin/sections' ,'SectionsController@getIndex');` and try again the section controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order makes difference, try something like this, just to see what happens:

```
Route::controller('admin/sections' ,'SectionsController');
Route::controller('admin/companies' , 'CompaniesController');
Route::controller('portfolio' , 'PortfolioController');
Route::controller('about' , 'AboutController');
Route::controller('contact' , 'ContactController');
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'SryoController@getIndex'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your urls, the routes are correct, and you might have something in the filters.php that performs the redirect, or maybe have you changed your 404 view